# SaaS or DaaS for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-workspaces

I have to host custom software on AWS. The user would run that software via a link provided on the website ( again hosted on AWS). I have the licence for the custom software. What AWS service whether workspace or any other should I use to host the software? Also, I have to connect the running of this software to a website, so please take that into the account. I am new to AWS and Cloud. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you should use ec2, workspaces are for virtual desktops.